# Add photo in CV template

Tags: templates, yaac-another-awesome-cv

I'm using a Overleaf CV template for my CV.
Nevertheless, I need add photo inside a defined structure (***experiences***), which is giving me a lot of problems.

The template is: [YAAC: Another Awesome CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-source-cv/wrdjtkkytqcw)
I need and tried:
[image]

```
\begin{experiences}
\experience
\raggedleft \includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{Linkedin2.jpg} 
{Currently}   {xxxxx}{yyyyy}
```

But doesn't work.

Can you help me?
Thank so much!

Comment: Please see the updated `IncludePhoto.tex`.  Increasing `\leftcolumn` will add space between the photo/figure and the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert  photos, logos or other figures, aligned with the rest of an `experience` entry you have:

(1) Put the file  `IncludePhoto.tex` in your working directory. Also the figures to add.

(2)  Add `\input{IncludePhoto}` before `\begin{document}`

(3) To insert the figure: (a) use the command  `\experiencex` instead of  `\experience` for the entry and, (b) add the name of the figure/photo at the end, between braces, for example `{linkedin}`

[image: x]

This is the main CV file

```
% !TEX TS-program = luatex

\documentclass[localFont,alternative]{yaac-another-awesome-cv}
\name{Christophe}{Roger}
\tagline{Architecte Logiciel | Développeur/Concepteur Java/JEE}
\photo{2.5cm}{darwiin}
\socialinfo{
    \linkedin{christopheroger}
    \github{darwiin}\\
    \smartphone{+687 123 456}
    \email{christophe.roger@mail.com}\\
    \address{2 Rue du quartier, 98765 Ville, Pays}\\
    \infos{Né le 23 septembre 1982 (35 ans) à Nouméa, Nouvelle-Calédonie}
}

% ***************************************
\input{IncludePhoto} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

    \makecvheader

    \makecvfooter
        {\textsc{\today}} % \selectlanguage{english}\today
        {\textsc{Christophe Roger - CV}}
        {\thepage}

    \input{section_headline}
    \input{section_competences}             % Section compétence
    \input{section_experience_short}        % Section expérience
    \input{section_langues}                 % Section langues
    \input{section_scolarite}               % Section scholarité
%   \input{section_interets}                % Section intérêts
    \input{section_projets}
    \input{section_references}              % Section références

\end{document}
```

**Updated** This is the file `IncludePhoto.tex` . Increasing `\leftcolumn` will add space between the photo/figure and the dates.

```
%%%%  IncludePhoto.tex (v2)

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\imagecolumn}
\newlength{\imagewidth}

%% **************** Adjust image and column widths
\setlength{\imagewidth}{1cm}            % image width   
\setlength{\imagecolumn}{1cm}           % image column width
\setlength{\leftcolumn}{2.5cm}          % dates width> minimum 2.5 cm
%% ****************

\setlength{\rightcolumnlength}{\textwidth-\imagecolumn-\leftcolumn-5\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}% calc Experience width

\renewenvironment{experiences}{%
    \begin{longtable}{c R{\leftcolumn}|E}  
    }{%
    \end{longtable}
}

\renewcommand\experience[7]{%
    &   \textbf{#1}    & \textbf{#2, \textsc{#3}, #4}                                   \\*
    &   \textbf{#5}    & \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnlength}#6  \end{minipage}      \\*
    &   & \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#7}{\cvtag{\n}}}    \\
}

\newcommand\experiencex[8]{%
\multirow{2}{\imagecolumn}{\centering\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,keepaspectratio]{#8}}   &   \textbf{#1}    & \textbf{#2, \textsc{#3}, #4} \\*
    &   \textbf{#5}    & \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnlength}#6  \end{minipage}      \\*
    &   & \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#7}{\cvtag{\n}}}    \\
}

\renewcommand\consultantexperience[9]{%
    &   \textbf{#1}    & \textbf{#2, \textsc{#3}, #4}                                   \\*
    &   \textbf{#5}    & \emph{#6} pour \textsc{#7}                                     \\*
    &   &   \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnlength} #8 \end{minipage}                   \\*
    &   & \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#9}{\cvtag{\n}}}    \\
}
%%%% end of  IncludePhoto.tex
```

With `\leftcolumn` set to 3.5cm.

[image: y]

Examples of the use of `\experiencex`

```
%%  section_experience_short.tex

%Section: Work Experience at the top
\sectionTitle{Expérience Professionelle}{\faSuitcase}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\begin{experiences}
 \experiencex  % use this command to include a figure/photo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {Aujourd'hui}   {Architecte logiciel | Développeur/Concepteur Senior JEE}{EPI}{Nouvelle-Calédonie}
    {Décembre 2015} {
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Reconstruction de la plateforme d'intégration                        
                        \item Migration de l'ensemble des projets Java sous Maven                    
                        \item Evolutions et corrections des bugs du framework de développement interne                
                        \item Veille technologique                                                                    
                      \end{itemize}
                    }
                    {Apache Tomcat, IntelliJ Idea, Eclipse, Maven, Spring Boot, Jenkins, Nexus}{linkedin}% name of the figure/photo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \emptySeparator
  \experiencex % use this command to include a figure/photo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {Novembre 2015} {Architecte logiciel | Développeur/Concepteur Senior JEE}{CAFAT}{Nouvelle-Calédonie}
    {Avril 2014}    {
                      \begin{itemize}
                        \item Support et encadrement technique des équipes de développement                           
                        \item Suivi, validation et intégration des développements externalisés                        
                        \item Implémentation, analyse et livraison de correctifs de bugs sur les applicatifs métiers  
                        \item Evolutions et corrections des bugs du framework de développement interne                
                        \item Rédaction des dossiers d'architecture en collaboration avec les architectes fonctionnels
                        \item Veille technologique                                                                    
                      \end{itemize}
                    }
                    {JBoss EAP, IntelliJ Idea, Eclipse, Maven}{example-grid-100x100pt}% name of the figure/photo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  \emptySeparator
```

Comment: wowwww thank you so much!!!! it's perfect!!! one last question, what's the value for control the distance between de photo and ``{Aujourd'hui}`` ??? I tried with ``\multirow{2}{1cm}`` but this is just for control the photo. Thank you so much

Comment: @Solid Please see the updated `IncludePhoto.tex`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! very appreciate